# How do I open port 443 on Windows server 2016 Standard

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have opened the port 443 on the firewall but still doesn't show it is listening both with netstat and telnet commands. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I think you need to define what you are trying to achieve here. What access do you hope to gain by doing this, what tool requires it, etc.

Comment: I presume you are forwarding traffic on port 443 to the local intranet address you have assigned to your server.  Just because you did this does not mean the port is open, or has any software that listens on that port, do you have software that is listening on that port?

Comment: I want to have an SSL binding on the specific port since it is the default https port so that I do not need to add the port on the URL for access; it is currently using port 80. I currently do not have any software listing on that port.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing traffic to go through using the firewall is only half of the work. There also has to be a program that listens on port 443. Port 443 is a very generic port, so make sure that the program you want to be using is running and listening on port 443. To give you an idea how generic it is: IIS can use port 443 for https traffic, and Microsoft Exchange can use port 443 for secure connections over https, owa, etc. Not to mention any non-microsoft program.

In any case, firewall or not, you should be able to see a program listening on port 443 from the server itself. If you don't even see that, then the program is not running or listening on port 443.

Also, don't forget, if this program has to be accessible from the outside world, you also need to create a port forwarding rule in the router, and if https management is enabled on the router, you need to change its default port from 443 to something else.